# Problems using ecpsf in Snoopy with IRAF

Tags: iraf

I'm trying to fit a psf to some stars in an image using ecpsf in Snoopy.
When I read in the image I get the following error:

```
snoopy> ecpsf filename
ERROR: Cannot open image (filename)
  "imget(nome0,"exptime")"
     line 37: snoopydir$proc/ecpsf.cl
     called as: `ecpsf (nome=filename)'
```

Anyone know what could be wrong here?

[Scientific Linux 6, IRAF 2.16.1, DS9 v7.3b5,]

Comment: Perhaps verify your're specifying the right path to `filename`. Try an absolute path. Getting further help from this community may be difficult because SNOoPY seems to be only distributed to "[very close collaborators](http://sngroup.oapd.inaf.it/snoopy.html)" of the authors. It may only be possible to get debugging help from them.